# buble sorting arrays and merge them without built in functions with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

hello i want to sort two arrays and merge there result  in 3rd array and  again sort it.
without  using in built functions

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function myfunction()
    {       
        var array1=[ 2 , 6 , 3 , 9 , 7 ];
        var array2=[ 5 , 1 , 8 , 11 , 10 ];
        var result=bubble_sort(array1);
        var result=bubble_sort(array2);
        var array=[];
        var i;
        var j;
        var temp;       

        document.getElementById("abc").value;
    }

    function bubble_sort(array)
    {   
        var i;
        var j;
        var temp;
        var len=array.length;

        document.write("Numbers before sort: " + "<br>");

        for ( i = 0; i < len; i++ )  
                document.write(array[i] + " " );

        document.write("<br><br>");

        for ( i = 0; i < len; i++ ) {  
            for (j = 0; j < len; j++ ) {  
                if (array[i] < array[j]) {  
                    temp = array[i];  
                    array[i] = array[j];  
                    array[j] = temp;  
                }  
            }  
        }

        document.write("Numbers after sort: " + "<br>");  

        for( i = 0; i < len; i++ )  
            document.write(array[i] + " ");  
    }
    var array1=[ 2 , 6 , 3 , 9 , 7 ];
    var array2=[ 5 , 1 , 8 , 11 , 10 ]; 

</script>
</head>
<body>

<p id="abc">SORTING OF NUMBERS</p>

<script>myfunction()</script>
<script>bubble_sort(array)</script>

<body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Merging two arrays -

```
function merge(arr1, arr2) {
    var arr3 = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
        arr3[arr3.length] = arr1[i];
    }
    for (var j = 0; j < arr2.length; j++) {
        arr3[arr3.length] = arr2[j];
    }
    return arr3;
}
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vikrant47/o4q91ptL/1/embedded/result/)

Comment: You're welcome! If my answer suited your needs, don't forget to accept it (same for the other [questions] you [asked] :)

Comment: People here just `down-vote` the ques & answer but don't comment the reason of `down-vote`.

Comment: @user3887505 I am not saying to you brother ,its somebody has down-woted my answer.

Comment: could u please tell me code for password validation without regex

i have created an array  of  var spcl=['@','$','%','&'];

special strings

i m not getting  how to validate  that  password  box contains  atleast  2 special  character

Comment: @VIKRANTSHARMA I think you have forgot to accept my answer. Bhai accept it otherwise I'll have to delete it as it's down-voted.Look also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235

Comment: thanks
as im new to this site
so i was not aware of  it